# Suggestions needed for optimizing O(n^2) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, hadoop

I am looking to optimize a fairly simple algorithm that is currently
*O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.  I have a file of records, where each one needs to
be compared to every other in the same file.  If the two are the
'same' (comparator function is pretty complicated), the matched
records are output.  Note that there may be several records that match
each other, ***and there is no sense of order - only if the match is True or False.***

Pseudo code:

```
For (outRec in sourceFile) {
  Get new filePointer for targetFile //starting from the top of the file for inner loop
  For (inRec in targetFile) {
    if (compare(outRec, inRec) == TRUE ) {
      write outRec
      write inRec
    }
    increment some counters
  }
  increment some other counters
}
```

The data is not sorted in any way, and there is no preprocessing
possible to order the data.

Any ideas on how this could become something less than
*O(n<sup>2</sup>)*?  I am thinking of applying the MapReduce paradigm
on the code, breaking up the outer AND inner loops, possibly using a
chained Map function.  I am pretty sure I have the code figured out on
Hadoop, but wanted to check alternatives before I spent time coding
it.

Suggestions appreciated!

Added: Record types. Basically, I need to match names/strings.  The
types of matching are shown in the example below.

```
1,Joe Smith,Daniel Foster

2,Nate Johnson,Drew Logan

3,Nate Johnson, Jack Crank

4,Joey Smyth,Daniel Jack Foster

5,Joe Morgan Smith,Daniel Foster



Expected output:
Records 1,4,5 form a match set
End of output
```

**Added: these files will be quite large.  The largest file is
expected to be around 200 million records.**

Comment: Give me example of record. pls. You have to know that you <b>can</b> sort your data any way, and it will be O(n*log(n));

Comment: Can't you read the entire file in a collection? You can then simply sort the collection and iterate over it to see which adjacent elements are duplicates. It would change it from `O(n*n)` to `O(n*log(n))`

Comment: If there is really no way to sort your collection (using whatever techniques - hashes etc.) then it will always remain O(n^2) since you will have to compare every element to every other element. This means you will have a complexity of "n choose 2" = n!/(2!*(n-2)!) = n*(n-1)/2 = 0.5*n^2 - 0.5*n == O(n^2)

Comment: We need more details about the comparator. The details of the comparator function will determine how much this can be optimized. For example, if it's byte-for-byte identity, you can use hashing. If there are fields whose ordering doesn't matter, you can use a hash after sorting the fields. If the files are equivalent if a program they describe fails to halt after a million steps when given the other file... not so easy to optimize.

Comment: The comparator function bascially return true if two records match. And is not a trivial function...

Comment: The files will be huge. I can't read them into a Collection in memory. 'Sorting' (if that is possible) the records does not produce duplicates to easily pull out. The results can be a 'close' or 'fuzzy' match.

Comment: Given your sample data, you could sort/hash the records based on the first letter of the last name of each person. Of course you'd still have elements which are equal in the sort/hash, but not equal according to the comparator, and in each such equivalence class you'd have to compare all pairs against each other. So it's still O(n^2), but at least you (probably) don't have `4*10^16` pairs to do.

Comment: So the comparison isn't even transitive?

Comment: The problem using mapreduce here, is that you need a common key to feed your reducer. How is the compareTo() going?

Comment: For Mapreduce, I was planning to use a TextInputFormat, so the keys would be the line numbers and values would be the records. I will iterate over the target record set (hoping to break this up using a different map) and emit the record from the source as the key and record from the target as the value. The Reduce will take the source records as keys and emit a list of the target records. 
Should work, Yes? 
My main concern is trying to split up the target file as well, since it would be like have two 'inputs' into MapReduce.

Comment: With hacking of the InputFormat and RecordReader this sounds quite okay. I could possibly have a better way if you can tell how the compare logic works.

Comment: The compare logic checks a number of things like exact match and fuzzy match on a number of fields in the record. it only outputs T/F when the source and target record match.
After thinking a little bit about this, I am not sure how I will handle the two input files (source and target). Initial thought is to place the target in the DistributedCache and iterate over it with the records from the source file, which will be split up by the TextInputFormat's InputSplit.

Comment: I would recommend you to implement your own writable key and value classes, and in the key let the compareTo() do the same logic as your compare() function. If it is false, you return -1 instead of 0. This is a nifty hack, but it works. Then you can submit all your files in one job. I can setup an answer for this.

Comment: actually this won't work... Just tried for myself. Mainly because each file output gets sorted in itself, and afterwards it gets merged. Merging won't give you the right result. Sorry, didn't catch that. If you don't mind, I would provide you a similar implemenation using HDFS and iterating over the file later on.

Comment: Thanks. I was just digesting it and came to a similar conclusion. I think the issue is how to distinguish between the source and the target file. Like I said one option is to place the target in the DistributedCache, and pass the source as a TextInputFormat to the Mapper (it should split the source file and iterate over the target in the cache). I am pretty sure this will work, but it seems like a waste to NOT be able to Map the target file into smaller chunks as well, and then have the Reduce work over chunks of both the source and the target.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1382/discussion-between-cbannerjee-and-thomas-jungblut)

Comment: I provided a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the files aren't ridiculously large, I'd go through the file in its entirety, and compute a hash for the row, and keep track of hash/line #  (or file pointer position) combinations.  Then sort the list of hashes, and identify those that appear more than once.

Comment: This will not work due to hash collisions. Why not just use a hash table?

Comment: The issue is designing a hash function that looks at only one record is not possible (at least, I don't know how that could be done). Also, the compare function can return true when bytes(A) != bytes(B).

Comment: Turns out a fairly simple MinHash type scheme worked out pretty well. It doesn't catch all the 'duplicates' but good enough for government work...

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure about the properties of your comparator and the data set, but assuming that your comparator defines an equivalence relation on your rows, here goes nothing:

1. Create a map for the input file and use the comparator function as the key comparator of the map. The map values are a sequence/list of rows, i.e. all rows that are 'same' get successively added to the same map entry). Takes O(n*log n) time.
2. Walk through the other file's rows and check if each row matches a key in the map. In that case, due to the equivalence relation implied by your comparator you know that this row is the 'same' as all the rows in the value of that map entry. Takes O(n* log n + C), depending on how many matches you have to output.

Note that in the worst case, according to your problem description, you cannot get any better than O(n^2), simply because there may be O(n^2) results of matching records that you have to output!

Comment: Hmmm..intriguing possiblity. I will research this!

Comment: A map is either going to be based on a tree or a hash table, and the problem doesn't lend itself to an ordering function or hash function.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I was just looking at the Map implementations, and I am pretty sure you are right - my compare function only returns T or F - not an ordering.

Comment: @cbannerjee But is it hashable? That's a different property to ordering.

Answer (score 2):

We'd need to know more about your comparison function.  Is your comparison transitive?  (That is, does A==B and B==C imply A==C?)  Is it reflexive?  (Does A==B imply B==A?)

If your comparison function is transitive and reflexive, and many records being equal is common, then you could bin your records into groups by comparing them to one "representative sample" of the group.  That could approach O(N) in the best case.

Note that hashing the records assumes hash(A) == hash(B) <=> compare(A, B) == true, but if compare(A, B) can be true even when bytes(A) != bytes(B) it might be tricky to design an appropriate hashing algorithm.

Comment: The function is transitive and reflexive. The issue is that the compare function can return true when bytes(A) != bytes(B). As a matter of fact, the idea is to identify 'similar' A and B.

Comment: @cbannerjee: are you certain that it's transitive? Measures of string similarity usually aren't. For instance, if `Joey` is similar to `Joesy`, and `Joesy` is similar `Joshy`, and `Joshy` is similar to `Josh`, does it follow that `Joey` is similar to `Josh`?

Comment: I'd recommend something based on grouping then.  Here's another grouping suggestion:  define a 32 or 64 bit integer as a set of bit flags that indicate the presence of some distinguishing feature that is likely to mean the records are similar.  Then decide which records to compare first based on the similarities of their bitmasks.  (Compare in order of bitcount(mask(A) & mask(B)).)  This is like hashing, but fuzzy.  Edit: You might want to look at AI techniques or datamining techniques rather than phrasing it as an algorithms problem.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: You are right. it is not transitive, but it is reflexive. I think I responded reflexively <groan/>

Answer (score 2):

FYI MapReduce will **not** imrove the algorithmic complexity of the solution.  It adds some overhead but then parallelizes it so that you can use the necessary resources in less wall-clock time.

To improve your wall-clock time the #1 thing to do is to find ways to avoid having to run the comparison.  Any way of doing that will be a win.  And even if your comparison logic is complex, you can still use sorting to help.

For instance suppose that you have some dimension that that data is spread out in.  Data that varies by too much in that dimension is guaranteed to not compare equal, though being close in that dimension does not guarantee equality.  Then what you can do is sort your data by that dimension, and then only run comparisons between elements that are close in that dimension.  Voila!  Most of the `O(n*n)` comparisons are now gone.

Let's make it more complex.  Suppose you can identify two such dimensions that are independent from each other.  Sort your data along the first such dimensions.  Divide data in the first dimension into strips.  (Make the strips overlap by the maximum they can vary in that dimension and still compare equal.)  Now take each strip and sort it by the second dimension.  Then run comparisons between pairs of elements that are acceptably close in that dimension, and include the pair in your answer if it compares equal, and this is the first strip it could appear in.  (That dedup logic is needed because overlap may mean that a pair that compares equal can appear in multiple strips.)  This is likely to be even better than the first approach because you've managed to narrow things down so that you're only comparing rows with a small number of "nearby" rows.

If you want to use less resources, you need to focus on ways to avoid having to actually make individual comparisons.  Anything that you come up with on that path will help.

Comment: Purely sorting the data will potentially not help because of the tremendous amount of variability in the incoming data. What would be ideal is to maybe alphabet sort the fields, and assign _some_ type of hash function to each row, and then sort on that hash. Unfortunately, I am having a hard time coming up with a clever hash to do that.

Comment: @cbannerjee: If the data has variability in it, *and* you have something that you can sort on and definitely say "this row doesn't have to be compared to anything farther away than that", then sorting will help a lot.  If not, there are a multitude of other variations on the trick that could help.  But there is no point in my enumerating possibilities without knowing anything useful about your comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

Just go through each record of your file and insert them into a hash table. At each step, check to see if the record is already in the hash table. If it is, then output it. This can be done in O(n).

Comment: +1. The OP will need to program an appropriate hash function (depending on the details of the comparison). But the hash function doesn't need to be perfect; even if there are some collisions, this should still be an improvement.

Comment: Therein lies the rub. I don't think there is a way to create a hash function... if you take a look at the data, I am not sure how the hash can be generated to fall into even a 'close proximity' type situation.

Comment: Oh, when I read the "same", I assumed it was an equivalence relation and implied transitivity. If it's not an equivalence relation then it gets very tricky...

Comment: Split each line into names, apply a canonicalizing transform like soundex to each name, and index the line under each name.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already mentioned, you won't have the luck that it is going to be better than O(n^2), but you can parallize this.

I have a working solution which will work with HDFS, you can extend this with using distributed cache.

```
public class MatchImporter extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

FileSystem fs;
private BufferedReader stream;

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
}

private void resetFile() throws IOException {
    if (stream != null)
        stream.close();
    stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(new Path(
            "files/imp/in/target.txt"))));
}

private boolean compare(Text in, String target) {
    return target.contains(in.toString());
}

enum Counter {
    PROGRESS
}

@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    resetFile();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
        // increment a counter to don't let the task die
        context.getCounter(Counter.PROGRESS).increment(1);
        context.progress();
        if (compare(value, line)) {
            context.write(new Text(line), value);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf);

    job.setMapperClass(MatchImporter.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
    job.setJarByClass(MatchImporter.class);

    Path in = new Path("files/imp/in/source.txt");
    Path out = new Path("files/imp/out/");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, in);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    if (fs.exists(out))
        fs.delete(out, true);

    SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
}

}
```

Using the input in the source.txt:

```
thomas
phil
jen
james
christian
stefan
stephan
john
```

and target.txt

```
john meat
jay hardly
```

will result in reducer output of:

```
john meat   john
```

The trick is that you can split your source.txt and do the compare stuff in parallel. This will give you the speedup, but won't get you better in big O.

**One big note here:**
You have to report progress using a counter, because the compare against a whole file can take forever. This will prevent your task from failing in distributed environment.

**Little tip:**
Try to split your source.txt into 64m chunks and make the target.txt to a `sequencefile`. This will gain a lot of speedup, you have to rewrite the reading things then.

Wish you the best of luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking of - Thanks once again! 
I will look into sequenceFile for the target so the iteration over that will be fast as possible. One a related note, I am still intrigued to try and MapReduce the target file to try and further parallelize the solution.

Comment: If you need help, feel free to come again with another related question. I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: thanks! I will implement my custom Reducer and I should be set. If I figure out how to MapReduce the target file, I will definitely let you know!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by btilly, you don't actually need transitivity to classify the records.  In the case of English people's names, you could represent each name by two initials, and each record by a sorted list of initials.  Then you only need to run the full O(N^2) comparison between records in the same class.  There is the additional issue that the same pair of records can appear in multiple classes, but it is easy to detect by maintaining a separate collection of matched record pairs (identified by record indices).

In the example, you'd put record 1 in class "DF,JS", record 2 in class "DL,NJ", record 3 in class "JC,NJ", record 4 in classes "DJ,JS", "JF,JS" and "DF,JS", and record 5 in classes "DF,JM", "DF,JS" and "DF,MS".  You get a total of 7 classes: "DF,JM", "DF,MS", "DF,JS", "DJ,JS", "DL,NJ", "JC,NJ", "JF,JS", of which only class "DF,JS" contains multiple records, namely records 1, 4 and 5.  Thus in this example you only need to run the full comparison function twice.

On the other hand, there is the problem that people have weird names.  [This blog entry on the subject is worth a look if you haven't seen it before.](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)  Whatever you do, you are going to miss some matches.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what percentage of the input is expected to match, or how often you might get an exact match versus an inexact one. If you can do a little pre-processing to reduce the problem size, it might be a big help.

If you simply sort the input and run your comparison function on adjacent entries, you might cull enough duplicates to make the n^2 second pass bearable.

Comment: I am trying to go back to the source to make the data sets smaller, and also see if there are some clever ways we can sort first to make the number of comparisons smaller...

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* can't do any better than an opaque equivalence relation, then your worst case will always be O(n^2) -- e.g., for the case where there are no matches, you will need to compare every pair to make sure of that.  (as people have mentioned, you can parallellize this, but that's still not going to be particularly tractable for hundreds of millions of records; it may not be worth the cost of the resources needed to do it that way).

Usually, though, there is some better way to do it.

If you really do have an equivalence relation (that is, if you have some logical guarantee that if match(a,b)=match(b,c)=true, then match(a,c) is also true), there is probably some *canonical form* that you can convert your records to, which is amenable to hashing and/or ordering.

In your example, you seem to be matching on variants of "Joe Smith".  If that is the case, you can probably augment your comparison criteria to choose one particular member of the equivalence class to represent the whole.  E.g., choose "JOSEPH" to represent all names equivalent to "Joe", "SMITH" to represent all names equivalent to "Smythe", etc.

Once you make that transformation, you can use a hash table to reduce your operation to O(n), rather than O(n^2).

Comment: The issue is that the function is not transitive. I am trying to reduce the problem size (by going back to the client and explaining the nature of n^2 growth) and then later merge the results.
I am also trying to come up with some sort of hashing function, which will allow me to 'stripe' sorted data and compare across some predefined range of the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the great suggestions.
After going through options, it seems the best approach given my timeline is to use a MapReduce framework to parallelize the problem and throw more hardware at it. I realize this doesn't reduce the O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.
The only possible solution I can think of is to run some type of minHash on the data, stripe the data into overlapping sections, and compare within the stripes and overlaps. This should reduce the number of comparisons, but I'm not sure how expensive the hashing run is going to be.